# Trying to install ecobee3 and don't have a Y terminal on my control board.

Tags: electrical, hvac, electric-heat

Went to install my ecobee 3, and when I went to install the power strip, there is no Y terminal on the control board. The only terminals on the control board are W1 W2 W3 R C G. At the thermostat connection, there are the typical R W G Y and no wire connected to the C board. On the control board at the furnace, the C terminal has a red wire connected to it, where a red wore is also connected to the R terminal. The ecobee installation says to install the corresponding to the terminal posts, but I'm not sure what to do considering I don't have a Y terminal. And at the thermostat, a wore is not connected to the C terminal.  The system is a Lennox CB30M

Comment: Can you post a photo of the existing furnace wiring?

Comment: Do you have an A/C system?  If so, it's possible that the `Y` wire from the thermostat, connects directly to one of the contactor coil wires from the A/C unit, instead of the furnace's `Y` terminal.   The other contactor coil wire would then connect to the `C` terminal in the furnace.